# Can I create an app based off a board game?

Tags: copyright

I wanted to create an app based on the Board Game Secret Hitler. The game itself is free to download on printable form. Because it is only available in Canada atm. I contacted the team behind the board game and they told me that it is not allowed to copy their game. So , what I am asking is, if I base the rules for my app off this board game, but everything other than that is different from the board game's design, is this still considered copyright infringement?

Thanks in advance for any info on this matter.

P.S. the app will be free

Answer (score 2):

### Game rules are not subject to copyright

That doesn’t mean you can photocopy them because although the rules are not copyright, the specific representation of them is. As are the design of the board, components etc.

Further, there will probably be trade mark protection of the name of the game and possibly other things as well.

So if you use the rules to make a game with a different name and a different “skin” and make no reference to the original, you aren’t breaching anyone’s IP.

This is a difficult line to walk; consult a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will for sure consult one before proceeding.